# Spring: When getting a ManyToOne entity, reference entity (OneToMany) is not showing in JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

When I send a GET request in POSTMAN to get all my child entity (Town) the parent entity (Province) is not shown in the JSON response.

This is my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value ="api/v1/town",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Town>> getAllTowns() {
    List<Town> towns = townService.getAllTowns();
    if(towns.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Town>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<List<Town>>(towns, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And these are my entities.

Parent Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROVINCE")
public class Province {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PROVINCE_ID")
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "province", targetEntity = Town.class)
    @JsonManagedReference("Province-Town")
    private List<Town> towns;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Town> getTowns() {
        return towns;
    }

    public void setTowns(List<Town> towns) {
        this.towns = towns;
    }
}
```

Child Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TOWN")
public class Town {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "TOWN_ID")
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROVINCE_ID")
    @JsonBackReference("Province-Town")
    private Province province;

    private long kilometer;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Province getProvince() {
        return province;
    }

    public void setProvince(Province province) {
        this.province = province;
    }

    public long getKilometer() {
        return kilometer;
    }

    public void setKilometer(long kilometer) {
        this.kilometer = kilometer;
    }
}
```

The response that I'm getting is like this

```
{
    "id" : 1,  
    "name" : "Some Town",
    "kilometer" : 350
}
```

What I'm expecting is

```
{
    "id" : 1,  
    "name" : "Some Town",
    "province" : { 
             //Province data.....
     }
    "kilometer" : 350
}
```

I was able to show something like this, but the Objects that I used are not Spring-data-jpa entities, just simple POJOs.

Is there any problem with my Entities? Or is there anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Swap `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference`. Basically:

```
@JsonManagedReference
private Province province;

@JsonBackReference
private List<Town> towns;
```

Comment: If I did that, my Parent Entity won't be able to display the Child Entity. I was able to fix it by referring to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615317/serialize-bi-directional-jpa-entities-to-json-with-jackson.