# JPA get join table data condition

Tags: java, jpa

There is an employee entity, it can have multiple address entities. I have added @ManyToOne of employee class to the address object

In most get calls i want to return only the employee object. But at times i want to return an employee object with an address list. How do I achieve this?

Something similar to what is happening in the below question. I just want to make it work on a toggle
[Spring: When getting a ManyToOne entity, reference entity (OneToMany) is not showing in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642650/spring-when-getting-a-manytoone-entity-reference-entity-onetomany-is-not-sho)

Comment: You basically want to look at "lazy loading", for example here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21648448/384674

Comment: Was this really a duplicate of that question? Same "dupe" was linked in question itself as a reference _Something similar to what is happening in the below question_ and IMO question is about howto control whether to return addresses or not? Well, maybe @RA26 could ask a new better formulated question with code for the classes if needed.