# Spring Data Rest specify lazy loading for collections

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have two entities with one to many relationships:

```java
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private Timestamp creationDate;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Role> roles;

}

public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

}
```

but when I call get method to load user information I can see in the log file that additional query to retrieve user's roles also called. How can I prevent it with spring data rest?

Comment: try setting fetchType as LAZY

Comment: it doesn't work with spring-data-rest entities. Also fetchType is lazy by default.

Comment: the default lazy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46684015/json-serializing-and-deserializing-with-hibernate-jpa-to-have-parent-object-into

Comment: What you have to shown is how you retrieve and manipulate the User entities. As a hint, enable the SQL logs you could see whether the query for the roles is performed in a second time

Comment: actually, I found that problem with show_sql property turned on, but thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2):

Define FetchType to `LAZY` as below.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private User user;
```

By default, JPA fetchType for ManyToOne is `EAGER`. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26601720/5296354)

Comment: I tried that approach and it didn't work. Actually, I loaded all users(not roles) so not sure how the mapping of child entity will fix that...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SDR, to prevent Roles from loading when you get Users you can:

1) Create repository for Roles. If you had one check if it exported (`@RepositoryRestResource(exported = true)` - by default just add this annotation without this parameter).

2) Or make User [projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts) without roles:

```
@Projection(name = "justUser", types = User.class)
public interface JustUser {
    String getUsername();
    String getPhoneNumber();
    Timestamp getCreationDate();
}
```

Then use it in your request, like this:

```
GET /users?projection=justUser
```